# Entity Framework: Update multiple objects only if all objects exist

Tags: python, c#, entity-framework

I'm writing a `PATCH` REST API in C# using Entity Framework that updates a specific field in multiple objects.
Request body:

```
{
  "ids": [
    "id1",
    "id2"
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

I would like to update all objects' `foo` field to be *bar*, **but only if all objects exist.**

I'm trying to keep it clean by not having a preemptive select that checks whether all objects exist (which BTW might not be good enough because if an object exist now it doesn't mean it will still exist few milliseconds later).

I'm looking for a short solution that would rollback and raise an exception if one of the objects didn't successfully update (or doesn't exist).
The only solution I found is to open a transaction and update each object in a loop, which IMHO isn't the best way because I don't want to access the database each row at a time.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: You have a bigger problem if you're trying to perform an update on an entity which may no longer exist while you're busy updating it. How will you handle that? And what should your code do, ignore it, add it again, throw an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DbContext.SaveChanges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges) method returns the number of entries written to.
In case of an update, it will return the number of updated rows.

So what you want to do is:

1. Start a new transaction
2. Execute a single update query for all you IDs together
3. Check the return value of `SaveChanges`, and `Commit` if it matches the number of IDs in your query, or `Abort` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! works well. would be helpful for others if you add a sample code.

Comment: @NoamGal if you tried and have working code to supply as an example, feel free to edit my answer and add it :)

Comment: (in general, feel free to edit and improve any answer on SO)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can come up with is the following:

```
var ids = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
var records = db.Records.Where(x=> ids.Contains(x.Id));
try
{
    foreach(var i in ids)
    {
        var record = records.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == i);
        if(record == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Record with Id {i} not found");
        }
        record.Foo = "Bar";
    }
    db.saveChanges();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //roll back changes
    var changedEntries = db.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
    foreach(var entry in changedEntries)
    {
        db.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}
```

The reasoning here is that EF implicitly uses a transaction, which is "committed" when you call .SaveChanges(). If something goes wrong, you simply reset the entities' state to Unchanged and never call SaveChanges().

Comment: You can fail earlier by checking ids.Count to records.Count

Comment: Definitely. The OP said he didn't want to, but you can definitely do it, seeing as you're iterating over the collection anyway.